# Adding number for duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel sheet that generates a name that will be given to the file based on information I fill in such as place, date and so on. The list ends up looking like this:

```
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15378 - 15415; 2023-12-27
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2023-12-20
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15415; 2023-12-27
NS1 - Sprutprotokoll NSA; 15415; 2023-12-22
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15415; 2024-01-10
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-12
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-12
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-17
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-01-26
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 011 - 014; 2024-01-26
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 011 - 014; 2024-02-01
```

Some of them are exactly the same and that is the problem. If there are multiple with the same name, I would like to add (x) value where x is a number 1, 2, 3... So it would end up looking like this:

```
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15378 - 15415; 2023-12-27
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2023-12-20
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15415; 2023-12-27
NS1 - Sprutprotokoll NSA; 15415; 2023-12-22
SS1 - Sprutprotokoll SSA; 15415; 2024-01-10
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-12
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-12 (2)
SS4 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 10 S 16+233; 006 - 009; 2024-01-17
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-01-26
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 011 - 014; 2024-01-26
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01 (2)
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 006 - 009; 2024-02-01 (3)
SS3 - Sprutprotokoll TVT 5 S 15+785; 011 - 014; 2024-02-01
```

I tried couple of times, but nothing really worked as I wanted. Right now it is easy to do it manually but I expect this sheet to grow into 1000+ entries.
I tried
IF(countif(V:V;[@Column1])>1; "(2)"; "")
at the end of each formula generating the name, but it added (2) at the end of each duplicate which made them duplicates again and if there were 3, it still added (2) at the end of each of them. Which is what I would expect, but not what I want and I dont know how to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, then using the following formula should work:

[image]

---

• Using `MS365` Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=MAP(B2:B15,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,COUNTIF(x:B2,x),IF(y>1,"("&y&")",""))))
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(B2:B15,LAMBDA(m,LET(n, SUM(N(B2:m=m)), IF(n>1,"("&n&")",""))))
```

---

Or, Older Versions could try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)>1,"("&COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)&")","")
```

---

If using in `Structured References` then:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDEX([Table],1):[@Table],[@Table])>1,
 "("&COUNTIF(INDEX([Table],1):[@Table],[@Table])&")","")
```

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A14,LAMBDA(x,x&TEXT(COUNTIF(A1:x,x),"[>1] (0);")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using power query.

I used this code:

let

```
// Load your data
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\1_RTU\Stack_Overflow\Numbering_Duplicates\data.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=3, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

// Merge your columns for easier calculations in the future
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"data"),

// Group your rows by the column (stores duplicates in a new table and asigns the table to the name of the duplicate)
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"data"}, {"GroupedData", each _, type table [data=text]}),

// add an index inside the tables
IndexedRows = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"GroupedData", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1)}),

// expand the GroupedData (choose only the index column)
#"Expanded GroupedData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(IndexedRows, "GroupedData", {"Index"}, {"Index"}),

// number the duplicates 
NumberDuplicates = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GroupedData", "DuplicateNumber", each [Index] - 1),

// format
FormatDuplicateNumber = Table.TransformColumns(NumberDuplicates, {"DuplicateNumber", each "(" & Text.From(_) & ")"}),

// remove unnesecary columns
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(FormatDuplicateNumber,{"Index"}),

// merge columns
#"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"data", "DuplicateNumber"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"DATA.1"),

// rename column
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns1",{{"DATA.1", "ColumnName"}})
```

in
#"Renamed Columns"

```
// now you can export the data as .csv or load it in a table in excel and use the data
```

you wanted to just number the duplicates, but I advise numbering every row. It will come in handy later on if you need to transform the data further on.
But if you want it without the numbering (0) just substitute it with *null*